# View a list of facebook pages that have added my facebook app

Tags: facebook

Is there anyway to view a list of pages that have added my facebook app (as tab).

For Example, i created an facebook application which allows users to add my facebook app tab on their facebook pages. Now, i want to see the list of pages who added my facebook app.

Is it possible using Graph api or Insights api? Or any other solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Concept:**

First of all get the list of the pages with-

```
/me/accounts
```

Then, for each page, `\GET`-

```
/PAGE_ID?fields=has_added_app
```

(`has_added_app` indicates whether this Page has added the app making the query in a Page tab)

**Permissions Required:**

`manage_pages`

**Complete code:**  (PHP)

```
$pages = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($pages as $page)
{
    $id = $page["id"];
    $resp = $facebook->api("/".$id."?fields=has_added_app");
    if(isset($resp['has_added_app']))
    {
        if($resp['has_added_app'] == true)
           echo $page["name"]." has used this app<br/>";
        else
           echo $page["name"]." has NOT used this app<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
           echo $page["name"]." has NOT used this app<br/has_>";
    }
}
```

(Or simpler way) you can use **fql** and query this-

```
SELECT page_id, name, has_added_app from page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me())
```

[Live Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/334261133294894/?fql=SELECT%20page_id%2C%20name%2C%20has_added_app%20from%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me%28%29%29)

Comment: Hi Shadowfax, Thanks for reply. But you didn't understand my requirement. My application will be add on merchants facebook pages not only on my own pages. The code you have probided will get my facebook pages only. i just want to know is there any way to list the pages that have install my app as an tab on their facebook pages.

Comment: `The code you have probided will get my facebook pages only`- did you tried the live demo? It will get you the user's pages with status that the app has been added to them or not. Isn;t this you want?

Comment: All right I got it. Wasn't aware of this feature lol. I'll get to you if found something on that

Comment: I've added a new answer pls check.

Answer (score 0):

To get **ALL** the pages that are using your app as a page tab, you could query following using `FQL`-

> SELECT secure_page_tab_url, page_tab_url, page_tab_default_name from application WHERE app_id=APP_ID

**Note**: `App_Access_Token` is required to query this.

Comment: Is your problem solved? You can comment if you have some doubt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query for a complete list of pages that have your page app installed.  You can only query specific pages to see if they have the app installed.

The only viable way I can see to keep track of the pages that have installed your page app, is to create a database table that stores the facebook ID numbers of the pages that access your app, and to have your server spot check those that haven't accessed it in a while.  Not an elegant solution, but Facebook API doesn't offer one at this time.